# How to input string for encryption using arc4?

Tags: c++, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, crypto++, rc4-cipher

I was using the Crypto++ library to do my arc4 encryption. Reference from here but not fully explained: http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Stream_Cipher.

The following is my code:

```
string key = "key";
string msg = "hello";

ARC4 arc4((byte*)key.c_str(), sizeof((byte*)key.c_str()));

arc4.ProcessData((byte*)msg.c_str(), (byte*)msg.c_str(), sizeof((byte*)msg.c_str()));
arc4.ProcessData((byte*)msg.c_str(), (byte*)msg.c_str(), sizeof((byte*)msg.c_str()));

cout << msg << endl;
```

My message after encrypt and decrypt which is totally garbage then i could not read.
not decrypted back to "hello" in short.

So how can I encrypt and decrypt message with key as above?

Comment: Try `ARC4 arc4((byte*)key.c_str(), key.size()));`

Comment: this the output: G?薿

Comment: you know that rc4 is insecure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems. First, you need to use the string's `size()`, and not `sizeof()`. Second, you need to reset the `arc4` object when decrypting. Otherwise, the cipher's state is continued from the previous encryption.

```
string key = "key";
string msg = "hello";

ARC4 arc4((byte*)key.data(), key.size());
arc4.ProcessData((byte*)msg.data(), (byte*)msg.data(), msg.size());

// Reset state
arc4.SetKey((byte*)key.data(), key.size());
arc4.ProcessData((byte*)msg.data(), (byte*)msg.data(), msg.size());

cout << msg << endl;
```